# Proibir acesso direto a uma URL (JS)

Tags: php, javascript, json, token, jwt

Eu fiz um site, e nele preciso impedir que entrem nele pelo acesso a URL, mas eu não criei session em PHP pq o login ta validado com token pelo jwt com js.

Tem alguma forma segura de só deixar quem se logou no site entrar em certas páginas com js?

Answer (score 0):

Esse tipo de ação vc precisa tratar no seu backend.
Ele vai fazer o redirect. Até pq ele vai validar o token JWT.